# Finding a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

The questions asks:

Fix a 3x2 matrix B and let W be the subset of $M_{24}(\mathbb{R})$ which consists of all the 2x4 matrices A such that BA = $0$ (the zero matrix in $M_{34}(\mathbb{R})$). Is W a subspace of $M_{24}(\mathbb{R})$?

I am not sure I understand the theory of this question or how to figure out if it is indeed a subspace or not. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have for $A_1, A_2 \in W$:
$$B(A_1 + k A_2) = B A_1  + k B A_2 = O + k O = O$$
$$ \implies A_1 + k A_2 \in W $$
$\implies W$ is a subspace of $M_{24}(\mathbb{R})$.

**EDIT:**
The above argument uses the fact that a subset $W$ of a vector space $V$ will be a subspace of it iff for any two vectors $X$ and $Y$ in $W$ we always have $X + k Y \in W$.

Comment: Yes @David!! Thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Comment: @CloudN9ne Please check the edited answer if you haven't yet.